# React component not handling clicks correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Note: please pull the repo to get access to the full App, there are too many files to simply share the code here. The repo: https://github.com/liviu-ganea/movie-database.git

So I've asked a question previously about my first React + Redux app and I've improved it. I got 2 problems now. The delete function for each movie (i.e. each entry in the redux state) is working just fine. So I now have problems with Login. Every time I press the button, nothing happens, and I suspect it's because the Login page component receives no props from the redux state.

**My reasoning**:

```js
handleCLick = () => {
  let userName = this.props.user.nickname;
  let pw = this.props.user.password;
  const nicknameBox = document.getElementById('nickname').textContent;
  const passwordBox = document.getElementById('password').textContent.trim;
  /*if (nicknameBox === userName && passwordBox === pw) {*/
  this.props.loginUser((this.props.user.isLoggedIn = true));
  this.props.history.push('/');
  //}
};
```

When commented as it is now, it should go to the home page whenever I click the login button and if the password matches doesn't matter. Only there is no reaction to me pressing the button. Is the problem as I suspect?

And another problem: see in Movie.js I've tried to get the path (it's set in state: movies: cover) to the movie poster (located in ./src) so that when (or if) I make use of an API the path should set itself dynamically (i.e. I won't have to go into every component and add the path manually). Same thing on the Home page (./src/Components/Routes/Home.js)...no posters for any movie.

After Comments:

**Component**:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './routes.css';
import { loginAction } from '../../actions/userActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Login extends Component {
  handleCLick = () => {
    let userName = this.props.user.nickname;
    let pw = this.props.user.password;
    const nicknameBox = document.getElementById('nickname').textContent;
    const passwordBox = document.getElementById('password').textContent.trim;
    /*if (nicknameBox === userName && passwordBox === pw) {*/
    this.props.loginUser((this.props.user.isLoggedIn = true));
    this.props.history.push('/');
    //}
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="container page-container login-page">
        <h3 className="page-title">Log In User</h3>
        <div className="login-box">
          <div>
            <label className="login-labels" htmlFor="nickname">
              Login{' '}
            </label>
            <input type="text" className="nickname-box" name="nickname" id="nickname" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label className="login-labels" htmlFor="password">
              Password{' '}
            </label>
            <input type="password" className="password-box" name="password" id="pasword" />
          </div>
          <button className="login-button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.user,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loginUser: (isLoggedIn) => {
      dispatch(loginAction(isLoggedIn));
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps, mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

**Reducer**:

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const initialState = {
  movies: [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'John Wick Chapter 2',
      year: '2017',
      main_actor: 'Keanu Reeves',
      summary: `The hitman that's been retired then back then retired strikes again, this time against the Mafia.`,
      cover: '../john_wick_2.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'Star Wars Revenge of the Sith',
      year: '2005',
      main_actor: 'Ewan McGregor',
      summary: `Anakin betrays Space Jesus so General Kenobi is forced to Mustafar Anakin.`,
      cover: '../sw_rots.png',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      title: 'Star Wars The Clone Wars',
      year: '2008 - 2020',
      main_actor: 'Ewan McGregor, Hayden Christensen',
      summary: `Yoda has finally overdosed on Ketamine, Mace Window hasn't been defenestrated yet and The Negotiator has proven himself incapable of falling to the Dark Side`,
      cover: '../sw_tcw.jpg',
    },
  ],
  user: {
    isLoggedIn: 'false',
    nickname: 'obi_wan',
    password: '12345',
  },
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'DELETE_MOVIE':
      let newMovieList = state.movies.filter((movie) => {
        return action.id !== movie.id;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        movies: newMovieList,
      };
    case 'LOG_IN':
      let newUserState = action.isLoggedIn;
      return {
        ...state,
        user: { ...state.user, isLoggedIn: action.payload.isLoggedIn },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
  return state;
};

export default rootReducer;
```

**userActions**:

```js
export const loginAction = (isLoggedIn) => {
  return {
    type: 'LOG_IN',
    isLoggedIn: 'true',
  };
};
```

**index.js**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';
import App from './App';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

console.log(this.props) for the Login component:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Movie.js**:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteMovieAction } from '../actions/movieActions';
import './Routes/routes.css';

class Movie extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.deleteMovie(this.props.movie.id);
    this.props.history.push('/');
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const isUser = this.props.user.isLoggedIn ? (
      <button className="delete-movie-button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Delete
      </button>
    ) : null;
    const theMovie = this.props.movie ? (
      <div className="movie-container">
        <img src={this.props.movie.cover} alt={this.props.movie.title} className="movie-cover" />
        <div className="movie-container-content">
          <h2 className="movie-title">{this.props.movie.title}</h2>
          <p className="movie-description">{this.props.movie.summary}</p>
          <div className="movie-data">
            <p className="movie-year">{this.props.movie.year}</p>
            <p className="movie-actor">{this.props.movie.main_actor}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {isUser}
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div className="center">Getting data about the movie. Please wait.</div>
    );
    return <div className="container page-container">{theMovie}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let id = ownProps.match.params.movie_id;
  return {
    user: state.user,
    movie: state.movies.find((movie) => movie.id === id),
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    deleteMovie: (id) => {
      dispatch(deleteMovieAction(id));
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Movie);
```

**Movie.js - every movie component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteMovieAction } from '../actions/movieActions'
import './Routes/routes.css'

class Movie extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.deleteMovie(this.props.movie.id);
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }

    render () {
        const coverino = ''
        console.log(this.props);
        const isUser = this.props.isLoggedIn ? ( <button className='delete-movie-button' onClick={this.handleClick}>Delete</button> ) : (null)
        const theMovie = this.props.movie ? (
            <div className='movie-container'>
                <img src={this.props.movie.cover} alt={this.props.movie.title} className='movie-cover'/>
                <div className='movie-container-content'>
                    <h2 className='movie-title'>{this.props.movie.title}</h2>
                    <p className='movie-description'>{this.props.movie.summary}</p>
                    <div className='movie-data'>
                        <p className='movie-year'>{this.props.movie.year}</p>
                        <p className='movie-actor'>{this.props.movie.main_actor}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {isUser}
            </div>
        ) : ( <div className="center">Getting data about the movie. Please wait.</div> );
        return (
            <div className='container page-container'>
                {theMovie}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    let id = ownProps.match.params.movie_id;
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.user.isLoggedIn,
        movie: state.movies.find(movie => movie.id === id),
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        deleteMovie: (id) => { dispatch(deleteMovieAction(id))}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Movie)
```

**The page display the entire movie list**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import './routes.css'

class Home extends Component{
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        const { movies } = this.props;
        const movieList = movies.length ? ( movies.map(movie => {
                return (
                    <Link to={'/' + movie.id} key={movie.id}>
                        <div className='movie-container'>
                            <img src={require(`${movie.cover}`)} alt={movie.title} className='movie-cover'/>
                            <div className='movie-container-content'>
                                <h2 className='movie-title'>{movie.title}</h2>
                                <p className='movie-description'>{movie.summary}</p>
                                <div className='movie-data'>
                                    <p className='movie-year'>{movie.year}</p>
                                    <p className='movie-actor'>{movie.main_actor}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                )
            }
        , )) : (<div className='waiting-for-movies'>Loading. Please wait</div>)
        return (
            <div className='container page-container'>
                {movieList}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      movies: state.movies
    }
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)
```

neither the require method, nor the simple {this.props...} works
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51FTy.png

Comment: Should I have edited the original question? The essence of the new question is different, even if the source is the same.

Comment: Please include a relevant code example here in your question in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example]. Links to external resources tend to suffer link rot. The code included in your question should be a "snapshot" of it in the condition it is at this moment, so it is preserved with your question. Please also try to limit the number of questions/issues, it needs to be more focused. Can we see the component with the click handler, and how that component is connected to your redux store?

Comment: I'll add the component, the Reducer, Action and the index.js (where I create the store)

EDIT: Done.

Comment: Have you verified (1) that the `handleCLick` callback is called? (2) is `Login` receiving the route props so the `history` object is accessible? (3) are there any errors being thrown *before* the code gets to the navigation action? It seems your `loginAction` action object doesn't have a `payload` property so is that throwing an error when you attempt to access `payload.isLoggedIn`? Try to reduce the complexity of your callback until it works, then you can narrow down what is causing issue.

Comment: I solved everything apart from setting dynamically the path to the img (className='movie-cover') via props (as in getting the path from the store and sending it to props (I already did that) and then from props to <img> ...) .... I'll insert the code at the end ....